# How can I dynamically parse markdown in JavaScript and use custom CSS styling?

Tags: javascript, css, markdown, styling, bootswatch

I want to use a service like [StrapdownJS](http://strapdownjs.com/) to create HTML pages written in Markdown. StrapdownJS functions well as a Markdown parser, however it does not fulfill my needs for custom styling. In strapdownJS, you select a theme like so:

```
<xmp theme="united">
    # Markdown here...
</xmp>
```

However, embedding a `<link>` or `<style>` tag in the `<head>` does not work, as StrapdownJS does all of the styling AFTER the head is loaded. So far the only solution I can think of is to programmatically alter all of the styling with something like JQuery, which largely defeats the purpose of having stylesheets in the first place.

Does anybody have a good solution for this? My ideal solution would look something like this

1. use `<link>` to include a CSS stylesheet
2. specify a markdown file (e.g., `content.md`)
3. Markdown gets parsed and rendered as HTML with styling from `style.css`

Please let me know if there is anything similar to this. Again, StrapdownJS would be perfect if not for its extremely limited selection of themes - it only has a handful of themes from [Bootswatch](https://bootswatch.com/).

Comment: What about something like [Markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it)? It'll give you the parsed HTML, which you can either send to the client if you're doing it servside, or render using jQuery or vanilla Javascript if you're parsing the markdown on the client side. Since it's just normal HTML, you can use any CSS you like.

Answer (score 2):

I found a more elegant approach using [MarkedJS](https://github.com/chjj/marked).
All you have to do is import your stylesheet along with MarkedJS.

Given:

```
dir
 |- style.css
 |- marked.js
 |- jquery.min.js
 |- content.md
 |- index.html
```

`HTML:`

```
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="marked.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
         $.get('content.md', function(data) {
            $('#content').html(marked(data));
        }, 'text');
    </script>
<body>
```

This ended up being exactly what I was looking for; I can keep the markdown in a separate file, and parse it dynamically while adhering to my custom styles.
You can of course do this without JQuery, but I much prefer this approach.